# How can I echo something and then clear it from the screen?

Tags: php

```
echo 'Removed from favorite art, Thanks '.(get_username($_SESSION['user_id'])).'~!';
```

I am currently echoing the above statement.  I would like to make it so the text is only on the screen for 1 or 2 seconds and then there is no text on the screen...

So (showonscreenfor1second(echo 'Removed art';))

Comment: You need javascript to manipulate the page in the browser. Unless you refresh the page of course...

Comment: One (PHP) option is `sleep(1); echo "Hello world";`

Comment: @Fred-ii- That wont work Fred. PHP is server side scripting, so even if it pauses then resumes, it wont be noticeable because it wont serve the page until done. You'll most likely just cause the page to hang for a second before serving it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a sample that I use on one of my sites:

PHP:

```
<?
if($save == "Save Changes"){
echo '<div id="message" >';
echo '<span>Your Settings Have Been Saved.</span>';
echo '</div>';
}
?>
```

Jquery:

```
<script>
window.onload = $("#message").delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
</script>
```

Of course, to use jQuery, you'll need to add the library in the `<head>`. I recommend Googles Hosting of it.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Adding a [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ueppkqc4/) for you too, since you can't get it to work for whatever reason.

Comment: Is 'jquery' the only easy way? I do not know

Comment: @RyanVincent well, can use ajax too if you dont want to do page reloads. Just depends on application.

Comment: @RyanVincent No, you can even use css transitions to manipulate for example `max-height` but getting the delay right might be a bit more tricky accross browsers. And in general a js library will make your animation easier than doing it in plain js.

Comment: [pure javascript fade in/out of element on code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/7323/29741) (there are several answers given; take a look at all of them)

Comment: I tried this in 2 places, can't get either to work.  I am echoing the div that I want to disappear, but it's not going away.

Comment: @JamesLyngaas - what browser are you using?  in chrome, press control+alt+j and in IE press F12 and firefox also press F12.  This should open a panel on the bottom of the screen.  Look for errors and see what your javascript is doing.  If you chose to use jquery, make sure you include the source before you use the script.  Make sure that your div has the correct ID.

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<div id="message">the message goes here</div>

<script>$('#message').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow').hide(0);</script>
```

The `<script src="...>` can go anywhere as long as it is done before the `$("#message")` script.

and this also works for me, without jquery:

```
<div id="message">the message goes here</div>

<script> 

    function fade(element) {
        var op = 1;  // initial opacity
        var timer = setInterval(function () {
            if (op <= 0.1){
                clearInterval(timer);
                element.style.display = 'none';
            }
            element.style.opacity = op;
            element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
            op -= op * 0.1;
        }, 50);
    } 

    var elem = document.getElementById("message");

    setTimeout(function(){fade(elem);}, 2000);

</script>
```